# Delphi - Open project programmatically in IDE

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I would open .dproj files programmatically with embarcadero studio.
I know the path to dproj file and path to bds.exe, how can i do it?

Comment: If you double-click a project file it opens in Delphi. That means that you should just be able to "shell execute" the file. Alternatively call bds with the filename as the first parameter.

Comment: yet tried both solutions and doesn't work: opening the file does nothing, calling bds with filename as parameter open the IDE but does not open the project

Comment: Works opening file directly, probably it was not working due to an implicit cast gone wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a delphi project from a cmd with the command:
`"C:\DelphiInstallation\bin\bds.exe" -pDelphi "C:\Source\YourProjectFile.dproj"`

From within Delphi you can use this code:

```
 ShellExecute(Application.Handle,
  'open',
  PChar('"C:\DelphiInstallation\bin\bds.exe"'),
  PChar('-pDelphi "C:\Source\YourProjectFile.dproj"'),
  nil,
  SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Comment: Nice! This will open it in a new IDE. I was missing the double quotes around the filename

Comment: 1. `CreateProcess` is the right API to use to create a new process. 2. If you must involve the shell (no need to here), but if you must then use `ShellExecuteEx` because it has sane error reporting.

Comment: AFAIK double-clicking in explorer uses bdslauncher.exe, *not* bds.exe. Maybe this causes the "new IDE" issue.

Comment: FWIW, if the strings are literals, you can omit the PChar() casts: `ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', '"C:\etc.."', '-pDelphi "C:\Source\etc..."', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: But how to open the project in the RUNNING IDE without creating another BDS.exe instance?